# group by time and other column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe containing columns timestamp, name, and value

```
index    timestamp                     name   value
0        1999-12-31 23:59:59.000107    A      16
1        1999-12-31 23:59:59.000385    B      12
2        1999-12-31 23:59:59.000404    C      25 
3        1999-12-31 23:59:59.000704    B      15
4        1999-12-31 23:59:59.001281    A      300
5        1999-12-31 23:59:59.002211    C      20
6        1999-12-31 23:59:59.002367    C      3
```

I want to group by time buckets (say 20ms or 20 minutes) and name, and calculate the average value for each group.

What is the most efficient manner to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `pd.Grouper`, but it requires you to have the timestamps on the index. So you could try something like:

```
df.set_index('timestamp').groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='20Min'), 'name']).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: `pd.TimeGrouper` is now deprecated and the proper way to do this is to instead use `pd.Grouper`.

Comment: To see the specs for the `freq`, look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Comment: Great answer. How about if we want to count the missing value of specific column after grouping. how can we count it

Comment: @user2064809 You probably need to use `isnull` and `groupby`. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106954/using-isnull-and-groupby-on-a-pandas-dataframe