# Using isnull() and groupby() on a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a dataframe df with columns 'A', 'B', 'C'.
I would like to count the number of null values in column 'B' as grouped by 'A' and make a dictionary out of it:

Tried the following by failed:
`df.groupby('A')['B'].isnull().sum().to_dict()`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 24):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2] * 3, B=[1, 2, None, 4, None, None]))

df

   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  1  NaN
3  2  4.0
4  1  NaN
5  2  NaN
```

---

**Option 1**

```
df['B'].isnull().groupby(df['A']).sum().to_dict()

{1: 2.0, 2: 1.0}
```

---

**Option 2**

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum()).to_dict()

{1: 2, 2: 1}
```

---

**Option 3**
Getting creative

```
df.A[df.B.isnull()].value_counts().to_dict()

{1: 2, 2: 1}
```

---

**Option 4**

```
from collections import Counter

dict(Counter(df.A[df.B.isnull()]))

{1: 2, 2: 1}
```

---

**Option 5**

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for t in df.itertuples():
    d[t.A] += pd.isnull(t.B)
dict(d)

{1: 2, 2: 1}
```

---

**Option 6**
Unnecessarily complicated

```
(lambda t: dict(zip(t[1], np.bincount(t[0]))))(df.A[df.B.isnull()].factorize())

{1: 2, 2: 1}
```

---

**Option 7**

```
df.groupby([df.B.isnull(), 'A']).size().loc[True].to_dict()

{1: 2, 2: 1}
```

Comment: It is real hard to find a method outside your box :)

Comment: @BENY the whole 7 options by the price of 1 answer, nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Or using the different between `count` and `size` ,see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

```
(df.groupby('A')['B'].size()-df.groupby('A')['B'].count()).to_dict()
Out[119]: {1: 2, 2: 1}
```