# Using fillna in a dataframe with applied value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a `dataframe` that has a value of None for a small number of rows. It's something like this:

```
id     parent_id
1      1001
2      1001
3      1002
4      1002
5      None
```

Now I want to assign a `uuid4()` to every record where the value is `None`.

I'm currently using this method based on [Using isnull() and groupby() on a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106954/using-isnull-and-groupby-on-a-pandas-dataframe)

```
df['uuid'] = df.apply(lambda _: uuid.uuid4(), axis = 1)
df['parent_id_na'] = df['parent_id'].fillna(df_asins['uuid'])
```

The downside is that generating a `uuid` for every single value is very time consuming and most of them are thrown away later. Is there a better way to trigger an apply function on only those values where `parent_id == None`

I have tried below:

```
df = df.assign(parent_id = lambda x: x['parent_id'] if not (x['parent_id'].isnull) else uuid.uuid4())
```

But this returns a single `uuid` for all values, even if there is a non-None value in `parent_id`.

Comment: So you are saying all in the parent_id are uuid after the assign? seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.where(df['parent_id'].isnull(), uuid.uuid4(), float("nan"))
df["parent_id"] = df['parent_id'].where(~df['parent_id'].isnull(), a)
```

Try something like this. I ussually float("nan") instead of None, even though this works with None as well.